# locator.click: Error while parsing selector

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am seeing **Error:** locator.click: Error while parsing selector `'link', { name: 'Login' }` - unexpected symbol "'" at position 0

locator.js

```
export const loginTab = "'link', { name: 'Login' }";
```

login.js

```
const {loginTab} = require('../locator.js');

class LoginPage {
    constructor(page) {
      super(page);
    }
  
    async clickOnLoginTab() {
      await this.page.getByRole(loginTab).click();
    }
}
```

If the locator is in the same file, it works as expected.

```
class LoginPage {
    constructor(page) {
      super(page);
    }
  
    async clickOnLoginTab() {
      await this.page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Login' }).click();
    }
}
```

I created a separate locator.js file to add all locators associated to the page. On the login.js page I created a method to click on the Login Tab.

Actual: Seeing an error while parsing a selector.
Expected: Should be able to click on the element.

I am new to Javascript, can anyone explain what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a typo in login.js - fix that first :)

Comment: You can't turn a string into JS arguments like that. You could use an array of arguments, `loginTab = ['link', { name: 'Login' }]` and use with `getByRole(...loginTab)` but the whole design seems [fishy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). Why not just inline the arguments so it's clear? If you're worried about repetition, maybe use a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

As [ggorlen noted in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261096/locator-click-error-while-parsing-selector#comment132806086_75261096), you’re passing loginTab all as a string, instead of the two arguments of string and object, and can use an array of those two to spread into the arguments of `getByRole`.

That being said, the solution I would actually recommend is similar to what he said about just inlining the info. Page objects *are* the place to store those locators, as that’s one of the main points of the design pattern. For reuse though, you can make the locator a property of the class instance in the constructor, like so:

```js
constructor(page) {
    super(page);
    this.loginTab = await this.page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Login' });
}
```

Then within the class methods you can just reference `this.loginTab`, or in the tests even do something like `await loginPage.loginTab.click()`.

Note that when considering where to put it that usually those locators would live on the page object representing the page where those locators/elements actually reside as well.

Hope that helps!